# Move array index when a certain index is reached in another array

Tags: php, arrays, traversal

I have an array of values that I need to hash using different hash algorithms, the hash types array contains all the hashing algorithms name's.
I want to switch the hashing algorithm for each set of values from the values array using the hash_rotation value, in this instance, I would like to switch the `$hash_types` for each 3 values of values array, but the problem is when the `$hash_types` array is exhausted, I would like to go back to it's first element and use it.

```
$hash_rotation = 3;

$hash_types = [
'type_1',
'type_2',
'type_3',
'type_4'
];

$values = [
'something goes 1',
'something goes 2',
'something goes 3',
'something goes 4',
'something goes 5',
'something goes 6',
'something goes 7',
'something goes 8',
'something goes 9',
'something goes 10',
'something goes 11'
];

$current_item = 0;

function rotate_hash($index) {

    global $hash_types;
    global $hash_rotation;
    global $current_item;

    if (($index) % $hash_rotation === 0) {
        $current_item++;
        if ($current_item >= count($hash_types))
            $current_item = 0;
    }

}

foreach ($values as $index => $value) {
    rotate_hash($index);
}
```

Comment: Not sure i understand what yo want to acheive exactly but you might be looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php that run a callback on every element of the array and http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php that combine kets from one array to the value of another. When working with arrays be aware that some function returns a new array and other pass the array by reference.

Comment: well, the purpose here is to apply a hash function to a certain number of elements from $values array, that number is the hash_rotation variable, in this case 3, so when i hash 3 items from the values array i go to next hash type in hash_types array, and so on, but if i still have elements to hash in values and the end of hash_types is reached, i want to go back to the first element of hash_types and continue the process until all the values in values array are processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to take advantage of array pointer manipulations with `next()` and `current()`:

```
$i  =   0;
# Loop values
foreach($values as $value) {
    # Get the current value of the hash
    $curr   =   current($hash_types);
    # If the count is equal or higher than what you want
    if($i >= $hash_rotation) {
        # Move the pointer to the next key/value in the hash array
        $curr   =   next($hash_types);
        # If you are at the end of the array
        if($curr === false) {
            # Reset the internal pointer to the beginning
            reset($hash_types);
            # Get the current hash value
            $curr   =   current($hash_types);
        }
    }
    # Increment
    $i++;

    echo $value.'=>'.$curr.'<br />';
}
```

Gives you:

```
something goes 1=>type_1
something goes 2=>type_1
something goes 3=>type_1
something goes 4=>type_2
something goes 5=>type_3
something goes 6=>type_4
something goes 7=>type_1
something goes 8=>type_2
something goes 9=>type_3
something goes 10=>type_4
something goes 11=>type_1
```

Comment: spot on, that helped.